# Web application network or sql error when trying to launch instance of site via Internet Information Services

Tags: sql-server, api, networking, web-applications

Trying to do this exercise. I have an issue. I'm trying to launch an instance of this API. I'm installing the files locally and trying to publish the site/ api via Internet Information Services (IIS). My files / site are supposed to be communicating with a company's server and the web app is therefore supposed to launch. The directions have me install SQL Server Express local db, which is the utility that I believe is supposed to help communicate with the company's server. By the way, I'm on Windows 10.

When I follow all the directions and hit browse on the site from IIS, I keep getting this error. Can anyone please possibly help me?? I have tried all sorts of stuff. The sql express local db doesn't even have a UI so I've been able to start it from command line, so I know it's running, but still nothing. Anyone?

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
>   )]

[please click here to see the error screen I keep getting in browser upon trying to launch instance of this web application/api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdMi1.png)

[please click here to see the error screen I keep getting in browser upon trying to launch instance of this web application/api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5E2H.png)

Comment: Are you trying to query the company's SQL Server on a different machine? No need to install a separate SQL Server Express localdb instance on your web server for that.

Comment: The directions simply had me install it. I extracted the contents of file download, and in there there is a sqlserverexpress file, and the directions say to install it. So I did so. But then after configuring the rest of the settings in IIS I am getting that error.

Comment: Can you share how you are specifying the server name in your connectionstring?

Comment: I don't believe that I specified server name in connection string. That wasn't part of the directions I don't think.

Comment: I don't believe that I specified server name in connection string. That wasn't part of the directions I don't think.  https://campuslogicinc.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/folders/5000284765     I was just trying to follow the first like 6 steps here up until where it says to launch. The directions are for a windows server but I was told to just do it on any windows machine. So I'm downloading zip file, i'm changing features in "add windows features", I'm changing the folder permissions, then configuring IIS, then trying to launch to the landing page and that's when I get the error.

Comment: Do you have `CampusLogic.mdf` file in App_Data folder? Also, ensure you have performed this step: https://campuslogicinc.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/5000720792-file-path-permissions

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Yes, Moshin. I did in fact do the step you mentioned. Also, I just check and I definitely have the CampusLogic.mdf in the App_Data folder. not sure what to with it, if anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile/

So basically you need to set **setProfileEnvironment=true** and **loadUserProfile=true** for your application pool. **loadUserProfie** setting can be set using Applicaiton Pool advanced setting via IIS Manager but setProfileEnvironment requires editing of**ApplcationHost.config** file

1. Go to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config and open applicationHost.config in text editor.
2. Search for your applicaiton pool name e.g. DefaultAppPool
3. Set loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" for your application pool:

   `<add name="DefaultAppPool" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true"`

   Remember to restart Application pool after editing the file.

Hope this helps

Comment: That second step is what it needed. Thank you so much, I can't express how grateful I am!  Set loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" for your application pool:  did the trick!